# How to use optional if it is present then call a method of this object, other wise return null

Tags: java, option-type

```java
Optional<CustomerEntity> findById(Integer id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(em.find(CustomerEntity.class, Long.valueOf(id)));
}
```

```java
public List<Booking> getBooking(Integer id) {
    return customerRepository.findById(id).get().getBooking();
}
```

The problem is findById might return null, so I want something like

```java
customerRepository.findById(id).ifPresent().getBooking();
```

I could do it by manually check the ifpresent() return value, but I want to make it one line if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) to get the behavior you want. But I'd recommend returning an empty list instead of `null`, which could save you some headache at some point down the line:

```
return customerRepository
    .findById(id)
    .map(CustomerEntity::getBooking)
    .orElse(List.of());
```

By returning `List.of()` in the default case, you can also be sure that the returned empty list cannot be altered by adding elements afterwards.

Comment: This is the correct way to fix the problem AND returning an empty list is a way better decision than returning `null`. Returning `null` in the overwhelming majority of cases is a code smell. In the best of cases, it makes your application more complex simply because of the forced checks for nulls afterwards.

Comment: I'd suggest not to return a `LinkedList`, but return an `ArrayList`, or `Collections.emptyList()`, or `List.of()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `List.of` is a good suggestion. Updated.